# vuejs target all anchor tag onclick

Tags: vue.js

I want to call a method when any anchor tag clicked. It is not possible to define `@click` or `v-on` on all element.

```
<a href="#">link1<a>
<a href="#">link2<a>
<a href="#">link3<a>
<a href="#">link4<a>
<a href="#">link5<a>
```

on jquery I can do this

```
$('a').click(function(){
   //........
});
```

How can I achieve it in vuejs

**Note: I have 10+ components in my app & `a` tag is spread every where in components.**

Comment: jquery will run with vuejs, so you can use same in vuejs also

Comment: Exactly what _"method"_ do you want to call? Is it a Vue instance / component `method`? What data needs to be passed to it?

Comment: @Phil I'll add transition (`transitPage()`) page when any `a` clicked in any component

Comment: Where does `transitPage()` exist? What data does it need?

Comment: @Phil I want to place it where it can invoke from any component like `App.vue` or `main.js`. No data required just I'll add some css on page transit when clicking `a`

Comment: Wait a second... Are all these "link" internal to the app? If so aren't they going through Vue's `router`? If so that's where you would create the transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a great idea, BUT you can "watch" changes. In this case to the collection of links and then attach an event handler...

*Note:* I didn't test this, but it should get you in the right direction

```js
var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#example',
      data: {
        linkList
      },
      // update the items in linkList when the DOM is ready
      mounted(){
        this.linkList = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
      },
      // watch for changes to linkList and do something
      watch: {
        linkList: function(){
          for( var i=0; i < linkList.length; i ++ ){
          LinkList[i].onclick = linkAction;
          }
        }
      },
      methods: {
        linkAction: function (event) {
          alert(event.target.tagName)
        }
      },
    })
```

**Edit:** After reading the comments regarding the goal, you should let `vue-router` handle transitions between sections. I assume you don't want to edit each component so look into [Dynamic Transitions](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/transitions.html#route-based-dynamic-transition) inside the router.

In this case, you would "watch" for changes to the `$route` data and do your action there:

```js
watch: {
  '$route' (to, from) {
    // to & from are data in the route object telling you which components are being shown
    const toPath = to.path;
    function(){
      // do some action
      }
    }
  }
```

This would function regardless of the tag used to trigger the route...

Comment: your answer is close but still looking for more efficient solution

Comment: Well, this isn't exactly inefficient since that list of links should only be what's in the DOM at any given time. However, this structure is counter to how Vue is intended to be used (Vue expects to respond to data changes).

Answer (score 4):

You could attach the click handler on the parent/container element, and detect the target/child element being clicked via the [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  methods: {
    clicked(e) {
      const container = e.currentTarget; // FYI
      const anchor = e.target;
      
      console.log(`${anchor.innerHTML} was clicked!`);
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="container" @click="clicked">
    <a href="#">Link #1</a>
    <a href="#">Link #2</a>
    <a href="#">Link #3</a>

    <!-- more anchor elements here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: still same issue because i have 10+ component and `a` tag spread every where

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can achieve it by defining the links under data and loop through the `v-for` directive

**First Way**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    links: [
      { link: "first Link" },
      { link: "second Link" },
      { link: "Third Link" },
      { link: "Fourth Link" }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
   onAnchor: function(e){
     console.log("Clicked on", e.target.innerHTML);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
    <p v-for="link in links">
    <a href="#" @click="onAnchor">{{link.link}}</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

**Second way**

Create a wrapper component for a and use the same throughout the application.

```js
Vue.component('An', {
  template: '#anchor',
  props: ['link']
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
   return {
     links: [
      { link: "first Link", text:'first Link' },
      { link: "second Link", text:'second Link' },
      { link: "Third Link", text:'third Link' },
      { link: "Fourth Link", text:'Fourth Link' }
    ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
   changeText(event) {
     console.log(event)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Anchor</h2>
  <p v-for="link in links">
    <An :link="link" v-on:on-click="changeText($event)"></An>
  </p>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="anchor">
  <p>
    <a href="#" v-on:click="$emit('on-click', link.text)"> {{link.link}}</a>
  </p>
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer, It will not fullfill my requirement as I want to fire method at any `a` click. There many pages (component) in my app & hundreds of `a` there

Comment: If you want to fire the same event fire from multiple components, you can take help of Vuex state management. I can add to the answer.